# Calculating components of normal to a surface

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

Let $S$ be the surface $−5x^2+4y^2+2z^2−4=−5$.
The vector $\mathbf{n}$ is normal to $S$ at the point $(3,−3,2)$ and $\mathbf{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{i}}=−30$. Find $\mathbf{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{k}}$.

I found the normal to equal $(-30,-24,8)$ at the point $(3,-3,2)$. But I'm not sure what to do after that. What am I suppose to do with $\mathbf{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{i}}=−30$? And how will that help me find $\mathbf{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ ?

Comment: As you can see, you were given the first component of that vector. $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf{\hat k}$ is simply the third component. For the record, the required normal vector might also have been a multiple of the vector you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct normal vector (I haven't checked the first part of the calculation) then:

$\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$ are the unit vectors in the x, y and z directions.

The question gives that $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{i} = -30$, which is consistent with your computed value for $\vec{n}$, i.e. it is the x component of your vector in Cartesian coordinates.

$\vec{n}\cdot\vec{k}$ is the z component of your vector, which is 8.